# Заголовки в истории тревог

Tags: дефект, локализация, тревоги

В истории тревог, доступной через ссылку в профиле из блока "Влияние":

[image: тревоги]

присутствуют проблемы с формированием текста заголовков выбранных типов тревог:

- Сообщение тревоги участника
- Полезный Сообщение тревоги участника
- Отклонённый Сообщение тревоги участника
- Спорный Сообщение тревоги участника
- Отозванные Сообщение тревоги участника
- Комментарий тревоги участника
- Полезный Комментарий тревоги участника
- Отклонённый Комментарий тревоги участника
- Спам тревоги участника
- Полезный Спам тревоги участника
- Rude/Abusive тревоги участника
- Полезный Rude/Abusive тревоги участника

Такие странные формы предложения присутствуют из-за обычного склеивания переведенных фраз, в процессе перевода которых контекст не был (нельзя было) учтён. В двух последних случаях также отсутствует перевод для `Rude/Abusive`.

Допускаю, что список неполный, т.к если тревог определенного типа ещё не было - их нельзя выбрать в списке фильтров.

Comment: Подскажите, что именно вы предлагаете? Решение средствами Transifex? Или что–то другое?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky пока трудно сказать, надо подумать. На текущий момент сообщение описывает лишь `дефект`, а не `предложение` по устранению дефекта.

Comment: Репорт на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911