# Неправильный род в статусе тревоги

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Неправильно написан статус тревоги:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть "Полезная"? Всё-таки тревога женского рода.

Comment: Тогда заодно "Отозванные" ->  "Отозвана", "Спорный" -> "Спорная", "Отклонённый" -> "Отклонена"

Comment: @insolor забыли про ["Устаревшие"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXVZC.png) -> "Устаревшая".

Comment: Но "*статус*" то у нас мужского рода. Если подразумевается "*Полезный статус тревоги*", то не вижу ошибки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавил 5 предложений перевода:

- [Полезный -> Полезная](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2399)
- [Отклонённый -> Отклонённая](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/3807)
- [Отозванные -> Отозванная](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1227)
- [Спорный -> Спорная](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1602)
- [Устаревшие -> Устаревшая](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/908)

Теперь ждём подтверждения от проверяющих.

Comment: Посмотрим, что получится. Текущий билд 2023.5.15.43432. Но проблема коротких строк в том, что они часто используются в разных контекстах, где перевод тоже должен быть разным. Если контексты не разделены на уровне движка, то нормального перевода достичь не получится. В частности, предлагаю обратить внимание на этот [пост](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911). И еще [репорт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4071/176217) на нашей мете.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хм, как-то не подумал об этом (Буду учитывать в будущем). Но разве эти слова используются где-то вне тревог?

Comment: Слова можно поиском по traducir найти в составе других предложений. Даже для тревог в разных случаях могут быть нужны разные переводы: например, "полезная" — для одной тревоги; "полезные" — как заголовок перечня. В оригинале это всё "helpful".

Comment: Для отозванной разные термины используются. При отображении в списке - это [Self-removed](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19050). Ждём новой сборки. Текущая 2023.5.16.43433.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, род неправильный из-за того, что на enSO тревога называется <kbd>flag</kbd>:

[image: Название тревоги на enSO]

А буквальный перевод - флаг (слово мужского рода, то есть *полезный флаг*). У нас всё-таки <kbd>тревога</kbd>, вот и неправильное окончание.

---

Переводы уже предложили, нужно подождать утверждения и применения.

Comment: В данном контексте flag это глагол, что можно буквально перевести как "пометить"

Comment: @andreymal но в списке полезных тревог не может быть глагол

Comment: Род "флаг" никак не связан с родом статусов тревог в переводе. К тому же "Отозванные" совсем не подтверждает эту гипотезу. Просто изначально переводили без контекста, вот и перевели как перевели. Еще интересно было бы посмотреть, были ли изменения перевода "flag", но скорее всего он никогда не переводился как "флаг".

Comment: @insolor не "переводили без контекста", а "контекстов несколько". Но они не разделены, см. [коммент](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12719/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8#comment55276_12722) под смежным ответом.

Comment: @insolor на самом деле может быть связано, если переводчик думал о "тревоге" как о "флаге".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вот кстати не понятно с контекстом, на сайте прямо сейчас отображается и "полезные", и "Полезный": https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqXyT.png, на traducir вижу только один helpful

Comment: @insolor traducir регистрозависимый. Там вообще регулярку можно использовать. Ну и на текущий момент учти, что переводы из traducir не подхватились ещё сайтом.